# How do you invert this function $f(x,y)=\left( \frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Does there exist an inverse of the following function with given domain?

$$f(x,y)=\left( \frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right), \quad (x,y)  \in \mathbb{R}^2$$

$$(\mathbb{R}^2= \{ (x,y):x,y \text{   are real numbers}, \text{ excluding } (x,y)=(0,0) \})$$

I know when the function is of a single variable its inverse can be visualised flipping around the $x=f(x)$ line in the $(x,f(x))$ plane, but how would you interpret the inverse of a function as above (more dimensions)?

Comment: Do precisely what you described on each of the lines through the origin.

Comment: the mapping is its own inverse

Comment: Worth noting that in polar coordinates, $f$ acts like $(r, \theta) \mapsto (\frac{1}{r}, \theta)$, which makes it clear why $f$ is its own inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f^{-1}(u, v) = \left( \frac{u}{u^2 + v^2}, \frac{v}{u^2 + v^2} \right).
$$
As for the graphical interpretation, if $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a function from the $x$-$y$ plane to the $u$-$v$ plane, then the graph of $(x, y, f^{-1}(x, y))$ (in $\mathbb{R}^4$) is produced by flipping that of $(x, y, f(x, y))$ (in $\mathbb{R}^4$) with respect to the plane $x = u, y = v$.

Answer (score 2):

If $g(u,v) = (h(u,v), s(u,v))$ is the inverse function, then $(f\circ g)(u,v) = (g\circ f)(u,v) = (u,v).$ That gives you a system of equation: $$\begin{cases}\dfrac{h}{h^2+s^2} = u& \\ \dfrac{s}{h^2+s^2} = v\end{cases}.$$

When you solve this for $h$ and $s$ (which is a simple algebra basically), you get a formula for $g(u,v) = \left(\dfrac{u}{u^2+v^2}, \dfrac{v}{u^2+v^2}\right)$